# Java play Ebean table or view does not exist

Tags: java, oracle, ebean

I have an oracle database and I tried to access to it through the Java play. Here is my model class.

```
@Entity(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class Customer extends Model {
    @Id
    @Constraints.Min(4)
    public Long customerId;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String customerCode;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String customerTitle;

    public static Finder<Long, Customer> find = new Finder<Long, Customer>(Long.class, Customer.class);
}
```

And I tried to tested it like following,

```
 // Find all customers
 List<Customer> tasks = Customer.find.all();
```

When I'm executing this I got,

> SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

How may I fix this?

Comment: if there a CUSTOMER table in the schema which you has connected as?

Comment: Yes. I have a table named `CUSTOMER`

Comment: i don't know java, but i do know oracle, and the message means there is no table in the required SCHEMA in the DB, double/triple check that you are connected as the user who owns the table, or maybe add the schema name to the name of the table in your code eg. SCHEMA.CUSTOMER

Comment: I tried. But failed.